# Why is this method not working as I would expect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, methods, jquery-plugins

I'm teaching myself java-script/jQuery and I'm writing a range slider plugin using jQuery UI's [Widget Factory](http://jqueryui.com/widget/) + HTML5/CSS. I have a method `moveLabel` that is working but not as I would expect it to - I can't invoke it the way I thought I should be able.

This works:

```
self.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    self.rangeslider('moveLabel');
});
```

I expected this to work:

```
self.moveLabel();
```

Can someone explain to me what the difference is and why the previous works and the latter does not (and/or point me towards sources)? [This is the current CodePen](https://codepen.io/beepye/pen/prEYxO?editors=1000).

I also tried to move the [mousemove event into the method](https://gist.github.com/beepye/7ffd05f19830c68303501b4c60479e55) also to no success (gist).

Comment: the first one states that the third-party lib has  class with function `rangeslider()` taking `moveLabel` as a parameter. Now you can call this fuctionn through the class object `self`. While in your second try  you are treating `moveLabel` as a function which is no where exist in the library class.

Comment: @AlivetoDie so is `rangeslider('moveLabel')` written correctly, or is there a more adequate way to write this?

Comment: Since it's a third-party library and it's using class concept so the way they used if perfectly fine(Because it must be tested and manipulated thousand of times and then come into picture). so use as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The first code which worked stated:-***

The third-party library using class concept.

It has function `rangeslider()` which accepts one parameter(would be different-names).

Here in your code it takes `moveLabel` as a parameter.

Now you can call this function through the class object `self`.

***While in your second try*** you are treating `moveLabel()` as a function which is nowhere exist in the library class. And hens it's not working.

Note:- A third-party library comes into picture after thousand of test-checks and modification,so i don't think there is any better way to use that function/parameter. So go with first-one itself. Thanks